# How to connect with Metamask and Smart contract?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, javascript

I am ready with my frontend design. I have only 3 files **HTML**, **CSS**, and **JAVASCRIPT**. So, I didn't create any project or **DAPP** to have other files. Now next step is to connect with **metamask** and smart contract for payment. I am not getting exactly what I need to do now. Do I need node js files? If yes, then how? or any other files? How to connect with **metamask**? I searched for many codes but didn't get anything. Can somebody explain to me?

Comment: In principal you can interact just with JavaScript (without using node.js). Please provide some more details what you like to archive. Is there already a deployed contract in a test network? If yes, the ABI will be needed to write a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could help

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      console.log('Connected to Metamask!')
    } else {
      console.log('Injected web3 Not Found!!!')
      var provider = 'http://localhost:8545';
      window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));
      console.log('Connected without Metamask!')

    } 
    console.log("account: " +  web3.eth.coinbase);
});
```